# Fail to get array data in v-for loop

Tags: vue.js

I did some research and it have to be a function. I tried to add a component in the object returned by the data() in script[(Ref)](https://codeamend.com/blog/how-to-fix-property-was-accessed-during-render-but-is-not-defined-on-instance-error-with-vue-js/), however it didn't work. How could I fix this warning?

`[Vue warn]: Property "shows" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance.`

Expected result:

[image]

Template:

```
<template>
      <div class="md:flex justify-center">
        <div class="md:flex gap-10">
          <!--  Calendar -->
          <div id="vanilla-calendar"></div>

          <!-- Day Details -->
          <!-- (!) Loop to display shows -->
          <!-- <div class="roll-box">
            <div
              class="show-column"
              v-for="(show, index) in shows"
              :key="index"
            >
              <div class="circle-bg">
                <div class="date">{{ show.date }}</div>
                <div class="month">{{ show.month }}</div>
              </div>

              <div class="show show-box">
                <div class="show-name">
                  {{ show.showName }}
                </div>
                <div class="show-desc">{{ show.showDesc }}</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div> -->

          <div class="roll-box">
            <!-- 1 -->
            <div class="show-column">
              <!-- L (Date)  -->
              <div class="circle-bg">
                <div class="date">15</div>
                <div class="month">JUN</div>
              </div>
              <!-- R (Shows) -->
              <div class="show-box">
                <div class="show-name">
                  Piano Duo Recital by Lucas & Arthur Jussen
                </div>
                <div class="show-desc">Hong Kong Museum of Art</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- show 2,3,4 ... --> 
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</template>
```

Script:

```
const shows = ref([
  {
    date: "15",
    month: "JUN",
    showName: "Piano Duo Recital by Lucas & Arthur Jussen",
    showDesc: "Hong Kong Museum of Art",
  },
  // show 2,3,4 ...
]);
```

Using script setup(Have to use script):
[image: script part1]
[image: script part2]

Comment: just to make sure, you're using ```script setup``` right ?

Comment: The VanillaCalendar plugin have to use script

Comment: have you tried adding ```setup``` to the ```script``` tag ?

Comment: Using script is work, but the left side calendar won't work. I have to use script to insert the calendar. Uploaded img to the post.

Comment: can you share your html ? especially, the one with the ```#vanilla-calendar``` id ?

Comment: Also, can you share all your javascript including ```calendar init``` and ```ref``` data ? based on your screenshot, i don't think you understand how to use composition API

Comment: HTML updated. Concerning the wording limitation(too many code is not allow), I just post the related part(calendar + that day shows list)

Comment: Script also posted in img

Comment: I posted my answer, you can check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all, selecting DOM element by using their id is a bad practice in vue.

I read the `vanilla-calendar` documentation and see that they got an example using react (or vue in general) [here](https://github.com/uvarov-frontend/vanilla-calendar#example-using-react--typescript).

So, i tried to code using their example like this:

```
<script setup>
import { ref, onMounted } from "vue";
// JS Script
import VanillaCalendar from "@uvarov.frontend/vanilla-calendar";

// Basic styles
import "@uvarov.frontend/vanilla-calendar/build/vanilla-calendar.min.css";

// Additional styles
import "@uvarov.frontend/vanilla-calendar/build/themes/light.min.css";
import "@uvarov.frontend/vanilla-calendar/build/themes/dark.min.css";

const calendarEl = ref(null);

onMounted(() => {
  const calendar = new VanillaCalendar(calendarEl.value, {
    settings: {
      lang: "en",
      selection: {
        time: 12,
      },
    },
  });
  calendar.init();
});
</script>
```

After that, i see that you also want to add loop somewhere in your code, so i add the loop data on the `script` like this:

```
const activeIndex = ref(0);
const shows = ref([
  {
    date: "15",
    month: "JUN",
    showName: "Piano Duo Recital by Lucas & Arthur Jussen",
    showDesc: "Hong Kong Museum of Art",
  },
]);
```

And here's the full code example that you can use. I already tried it and it runs without any error

```
<script setup>
import { ref, onMounted } from "vue";
// JS Script
import VanillaCalendar from "@uvarov.frontend/vanilla-calendar";

// Basic styles
import "@uvarov.frontend/vanilla-calendar/build/vanilla-calendar.min.css";

// Additional styles
import "@uvarov.frontend/vanilla-calendar/build/themes/light.min.css";
import "@uvarov.frontend/vanilla-calendar/build/themes/dark.min.css";

const calendarEl = ref(null);
const activeIndex = ref(0);
const shows = ref([
  {
    date: "15",
    month: "JUN",
    showName: "Piano Duo Recital by Lucas & Arthur Jussen",
    showDesc: "Hong Kong Museum of Art",
  },
]);

onMounted(() => {
  const calendar = new VanillaCalendar(calendarEl.value, {
    settings: {
      lang: "en",
      selection: {
        time: 12,
      },
    },
  });
  calendar.init();
});
</script>

<template>
  <div id="calendar" ref="calendarEl"></div>
  <div class="roll-box">
    <div class="show-column" v-for="(show, index) in shows" :key="index">
      <div class="circle-bg">
        <div class="date">{{ show.date }}</div>
        <div class="month">{{ show.month }}</div>
      </div>

      <div class="show show-box">
        <div class="show-name">
          {{ show.showName }}
        </div>
        <div class="show-desc">{{ show.showDesc }}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, I would take for reference. (^^)=b

Answer (score 1):

I see you didn't return your "shows" variable in the setup format. So Vue does not recognize the variable while rendering the template. This is what you should do:

```
setup(props) {
  const activeIndex = ref(0);
  const shows = ref([
    {
      date: "15",
      month: "JUN",
      showName: "Piano Duo Recital by Lucas & Arthur Jussen",
      showDesc: "Hong Kong Museum of Art",
    },
    // show 2,3,4 ...
  ]);
  return { shows, activeIndex};
}
```

Alternatively, you can also define the setup within the script and you won't have to explicitly return your variables and functions. Like this:

```
<script setup>

const activeIndex = ref(0);
const shows = ref([
  {
    date: "15",
    month: "JUN",
    showName: "Piano Duo Recital by Lucas & Arthur Jussen",
    showDesc: "Hong Kong Museum of Art",
  }
  // show 2,3,4 ...
]);

</script>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Final Ans (sloved):

Delete the export props & setup(props) and use

Template:

```
<template >
// Loop today show(s) 
 <div class="roll-box">
   <div
     class="show-column"
     v-for="(show, index) in shows"
     :key="index"
   >
   <div class="circle-bg">
     <div class="date">{{ show.date }}</div>
     <div class="month">{{ show.month }}</div>
   </div>

   <div class="show show-box">
     <div class="show-name">
       {{ show.showName }}
     </div>
   <div class="show-desc">{{ show.showDesc }}</div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</template>
```

Script:

```
<script setup>
import VanillaCalendar from "@uvarov.frontend/vanilla-calendar";
import "@uvarov.frontend/vanilla-calendar/build/vanilla-calendar.min.css";
import "@uvarov.frontend/vanilla-calendar/build/themes/light.min.css";
import "@uvarov.frontend/vanilla-calendar/build/themes/dark.min.css";
import { onMounted, ref, reactive } from "vue";

// Calendar
onMounted(() => {
  const vanillaCalendar = new VanillaCalendar("#vanilla-calendar", {
    // Self define for css overwirte
    CSSClasses: {
      // Next/Previous mth btn
      arrow: "vanilla-calendar-arrow",

      // Days colums
      weekDay: "vanilla-calendar-week__day",
      weekDayWeekend: "vanilla-calendar-week__day_weekend",

      // Days color
      dayBtn: "vanilla-calendar-day__btn",
      dayBtnWeekend: "vanilla-calendar-day__btn_weekend",
      dayBtnHoliday: "vanilla-calendar-day__btn_holiday",

      // Last & Next month days
      dayBtnPrev: "vanilla-calendar-day__btn_prev",
      dayBtnNext: "vanilla-calendar-day__btn_next",

      // Today & Selected Day
      dayBtnToday: "vanilla-calendar-day__btn_today",
      dayBtnSelected: "vanilla-calendar-day__btn_selected",
    },
  });
  vanillaCalendar.init();
});

// Day Clickable
const options = {
  actions: {
    clickDay(event, dates) {
      console.log(dates);
    },
  },
};
const calendar = new VanillaCalendar("#calendar", options);
calendar.init();

/* Show's data */
const activeIndex = ref(0);
const shows = reactive([
  // Show 1
  {
    date: "15",
    month: "JUN",
    showName: "Piano Duo Recital by Lucas & Arthur Jussen",
    showDesc: "Hong Kong Museum of Art",
  },
  // Show 2
  {
    date: "15-18",
    month: "JUN",
    showName:
      "Chinese Opera Festival 2023: Opening Programme - Peking Opera Theatre of Beijing",
    showDesc: "Hong Kong Museum of Art",
  },
  // Show 3
  {
    date: "15-30",
    month: "JUN JUL",
    showName: "Chinese Culture and Dance Festival 'Hong Kong Dance Expo 2023'",
    showDesc: "Hong Kong Museum of Art",
  },
  // Show 4
  {
    date: "15",
    month: "JUN",
    showName: "4",
    showDesc: "Test",
  },
  // Show 5
  {
    date: "15",
    month: "JUN",
    showName: "5",
    showDesc: "Test",
  },
]);
</script>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

`ref` can only been used for basic data type. For object or array. You must use `reactive` instead.

```js
const shows = reactive([]);
```

Comment: It seems noting change, shows still accessed during render but is not defined on instance.

Comment: did you use shows in your template? i found that you comment those code in template.

Comment: Of course, I tried the gravy code v-for loop replacing hardcode

Comment: and you must put your code in setup function, you put define shows out the setup function

Comment: This isn’t true. Ref can be used for objects and arrays and it is deeply reactive, too. In fact, it’s recommended now to use Ref due to limitations with Reactive. 

https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/reactivity-fundamentals.html